# new line in heredoc disappearing in file

Tags: bash, newlines

I'm echoing a heredoc into a file, but the line breaks are being lost

Running this script

```
#!/bin/bash 

NAME="$1"

mkdir -p $NAME

FILE=$(cat <<SETVAR
name = "$NAME"
type = "test"
SETVAR
)

echo $FILE > $NAME/$NAME.txt
```

With the arg: foo, results in the file at foo/foo.txt containing

```
name = "foo" type = "test"
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is it on cygwin? is your result from a text editor or a cat? in other words, could it be that the newlines are here but not shown (because of the win/linux endlines differences)? Have you tried adding "\n"s?

Comment: i tried putting in \n but it came through as plain text. was doing all through linux terminal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Always use double quotes for variables that contain whitespace:

```
echo "$FILE" > ...
```